# Gradle: how to add a jar to build but not export it

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using the Open Mobile API (SEEK API) in my project by adding the jar file to my gradle build:

```
dependencies {compile files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')}
```

it gives me this exception:

```
        java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:322)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

My understanding is I need to include the jar in compile process but exclude it in the linking and don't export it to my APK. this is normally done with a simple checkbox in eclipse, but I can't find a way to do it with gradle.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you add it to the dependencies block?

Comment: yes I have. I edited the question to reflect it too...

Comment: seems to me that the library is loaded twice! quadro check that please :)

Comment: yes and no. the library is not loaded twice. the classes in the library are present in the android. I need to find a way to use the library to compile, but not include it in APK...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To not export your .jar [THIS](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-eclipse-how-to-not-export-jars-that-are-dependencies-of-a-dependency/7590) is maybe helpful. (reads well)

Additionally:

Try this to get rid of the error:

> Go to modules -> dependencies, then set scope of the lib to 'Provided'.

here is my [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605898/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-ref-in-preverified-class-resolved-to-unexpect)

Comment: Apparently the provided keyword is ignored by android-library plugin. When I use it in my app, it works fine, when I use it in the library I use in my app, it is ignored...